# How do I delete duplicated rows, and choosing which ones to keep?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a df with "id" and a column with a boolean (yes and no)
I need to delete the duplicated ids but keep the ones that the bolean is yes.

| ID | .... | buffer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| br1 | .... | yes. |
| br1 | .... | no. |
| br2 | .... | no. |
| br3 | .... | yes |
| br4 | .... | no. |
| br4 | .... | yes. |

I tried this:

`df1=df[~df[['external_id']].duplicated() | df['buffers'].eq('si')]`
where "buffers" is the boolean.
It is deleting but not all of them...I still have id repeated with yes and no
Im working with more than 800000 rows

what Im expecting:

| ID | .... | buffer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| br1 | .... | yes. |
| br2 | .... | no. |
| br3 | .... | yes |
| br4 | .... | yes. |

Answer (score 0):

I think filter out for "yes" then clean the duplicates will solve the problem:

For filtering `yes`:
data = data[data["buffer"] == "yes."]

For duplicates:
data = data.drop_duplicates( subset=['ID'] , keep="last" )

Can you try out these ones? These two supposed to work

Comment: I think I didn't explained myself ok, because if I filter first by "yes" there will no be repeted "ids"..

Answer (score 0):

**First to drop the duplicated rows**

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

This uses drop_duplicates() to drop the rows that contain the same values except for the first time row.

**Now boolean filtering**

```
df1 = df1[df1['buffer'] == 'yes.']
```

This would filter and save the rows that are having 'yes.'

Comment: I already tried this too, but the id with "yes" is not always the first, so it might delete the wrong row

Comment: Hello expectations are not clear, it doesn't follow a pattern and your question is also not clear.